# WCF implementing cross cutting concerns using data contracts?

Tags: c#, wcf, architecture

I have all these cross cutting concerns that occur between a request to the server and the return response in my application. The request must be authorized, data validated, exceptions handled, etc. Some of these, like logging, do not require a response to the user client - I am not concerned about these for now. Others require a response. For instance if the request is not authorized then the request is going to get stopped in its logical tracks and sent back.

My app uses a per call strategy. There is no state preserved between calls.

Is it standard to wrap the return value of operation contracts with data contracts that carry flags such as WasNotAuthorized, WasNotValidated, etc?

If this is not standard, what solutions are standard for handling the metadata that must handled throughout these cross cutting concerns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this article](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=95). It descibes how you can effectively model your application in a way that you can write your WCF service as a thin wrapper and apply cross-cutting concerns by applying decorators, which in most cases prevents you from having to deal with the complexity of the internals of WCF.